# hazelcast cluster inside elastic beanstalk docker

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hazelcast

Can any one please point me how to establish clustering for hazelcast servers running inside docker in elastic beanstalk. I have exposed port 8080 and 5701 and use java based AWS config. Same AWS config works if i run jar natively but if jar is run inside docker issue with clustering.

Also I made sure that security group has port 5701 open.

Comment: when you start hazelcast instance in docker instance, does it bind to private  address of ec2-instance? of another address? Can you check the logs.

Comment: It bind to docker host ip, I verified it. I need  configurations for dockerrun.Aws.json to expose it to ec2 ips, I believe afterwards clustering may start.

Comment: it should bind to ec2 private address, i will make simple experiment and will answer you.

Answer (score 1):

I havent yet confirmed, but i believe you need to use the net=host option when starting docker. Beanstalk does not make this easy

There is a discussion here:
[How to customize the docker run command on Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968404/how-to-customize-the-docker-run-command-on-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: Also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103306/hazelcast-in-multinode-docker-environments-with-tcpip
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968404/how-to-customize-the-docker-run-command-on-elastic-beanstalk
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868686/how-to-make-hazelcast-nodes-installed-in-docker-on-different-aws-instances-inter

Comment: --net=host has some gnarly side effects that if you update your EB version at all it could fall apart so very quickly as you have no control over how they build their file structures.