# Unable to form Hazelcast cluser on a multinode docker environment

Tags: docker, hazelcast

We have a Springboot based Java webapp that includes hazelcast.  We are facing issues in migrating to Docker environment.  I think i am missing something on Docker networking.  I did try the options mentioned in [Hazelcast in multinode docker environments with TCPIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103306/hazelcast-in-multinode-docker-environments-with-tcpip) , but it did not work.  We use the plain hazelcast.xml

jdk
        false
        false
        false
        OFF
        ${hazelcast.ip}
        15
        30
        15
        60
    
    
        dev
        dev-pass

```
<network>
    <public-address>${hazelcast.ip}</public-address>
    <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
    <outbound-ports>
        <ports>0</ports>
    </outbound-ports>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"></multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member-list>
            </member-list>
        </tcp-ip>
    </join>
</network>
<partition-group enabled="false" />
<executor-service name="default">
    <pool-size>16</pool-size>
    <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE. -->
    <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
</executor-service>
```

HostIP                 Docker Container IP
10.151.16.27           10.42.236.108
10.151.16.209                    10.42.152.56

Host1
ip route output
default via 10.42.0.1 dev eth0
10.42.0.0/16 dev eth0  src 10.42.236.108
169.254.169.250 via 10.42.0.1 dev eth0

Host 2
ip route ouptut
default via 10.42.0.1 dev eth0
10.42.0.0/16 dev eth0  src 10.42.152.56
169.254.169.250 via 10.42.0.1 dev eth0

I start the docker by injecting the container IP into the hazelcast.ip environment variable.  The cluster does not get formed.

Please let me know if i am missing something here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hazelcast.ip env variable but you don't seem to have any members in the XML file.

Comment: @noctarius: I am referring to <public-address>${hazelcast.ip}</public-address>.  Also the docker container IPs vary whenever i start them.  Even i hard code them after viewing the IP, it does not work.  Hence i left it blank hoping that the fallback will be auto-discover.

Comment: It cannot autodiscover since you have TCP enabled. What is the deployment environment? Is there any service discovery available to be used? Looking at the linked stackoverflow question, it seems like they've built something custom to offer hazelcast.ip, certainly this is not a standard property that is available by default.

Comment: It is a microservice based architecture with docker based deployments.  Each instance of the J2EE webapp (with hazelcast) is being deployed on a separate docker container.  In the example mentioned in the question, i have used 2 containers each one a different host.  Please note the setup works fine when both containers are deployed in the same host.

Comment: It sounds more like a docker specific issue with the overlay network layer, as you said on the same host it works fine. If it is just about finding the other IP addresses, you'll most probably need a discovery mechanism like Eureka, etcd, or similar.